# Ajax DB Update PHP recordset refresh

Tags: php, ajax

Basically just after some advice here.

I'm looking for the best way to update a DB record.

My page is written in PHP and I coded an AJAX function to a PHP page which updates the DB.

This is great because I don't have to reload the page however once the request is complete one of the record sets has been modified so I would like to refresh this.

Is it possible to refresh this or do I need to re-load the whole page which kinda defeats the purpose of using the AJAX function in the first place.

I suppose I could display a DIV with the updated data but I would rather have the data refreshed if this is possible?

Many thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to reload just a part of your page, you can use jQuery function load() just like this :

```
<!-- index.php -->
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="reload_it"></div>
</div>
```

then you have 2 files :

index.php and dynamic_stuff.php

finally :

```
success: function() {
    $("#reload_it").load('dynamic_stuff.php');
}
```

Comment: @Paul: I would refer this solution.

Answer (score 0):

In the AJAX call use:

```
success: function() {
    window.location.reload(true);
}
```